# Cassandra and heap size

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm running a 5 node Cassandra cluster which also happens to run Solr on the 5 nodes. I've ingested and indexed over a billion items and currently this message keeps on being printed on the console;

> INFO 10:55:54,360 Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty
>   column families  INFO 10:56:03,897 GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 538 ms
>   for 1 collections, 2733064112 used; max is 3158310912  WARN
>   10:56:03,898 Heap is 0.865356257870536 full.  You may need to reduce
>   memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two
>   largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust
>   flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't
>   want Cassandra to do this automatically

I have 8G per node and I've set the MAX_HEAP_SIZE to 3G in the Cassandra-env.sh.

Could someone please shed some light on how I could resolve this please?

Thanks
Majd

Answer (score 4):

It may simply be that you need more heap - Add a gig or two and see what happens. OTOH, you may need more system memory for file caching as well - 1 billion Solr-enabled rows seems a lot for an 8 GB system.

Generally, about 40 million to 100 million rows is the maximum capacity for a Solr-enabled DSE node. With 5 nodes and 1 billion rows, your cluster has about 200 million rows per node. Sometimes 200 million can be accommodated on a single node, and sometimes not - flip a coin there.

Also, a higher replication factor effectively increases the number of rows that Cassandra will place on each node. So, divide that 40 million to 100 million row guidance by RF to get a decent target number of rows per node.

In short, you need a much bigger cluster, a minimum of 10 nodes, and maybe as many as 25 nodes. And with an RF of 3 or greater you could need even more nodes.

Comment: With regards to the 40-100 million row for Solr-enabled DSE node recommendation, in my case, Solr is running on the same node as Cassandra (same Data-center, SimpleStrategy) so your recommendation is for a Solr node running in a separate Data-center dedicated for Solr only?